# Add client ip to graylog output with Gelf.Extensions.Logging package

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, graylog

I am using the `Gelf.Extensions.Logging` package to send log info to graylog from an asp.net core 3 website, and I would like additional fields like current user name, client ip, user agent.

In startup.cs, I have the following, but I don't know how to add the data to `AdditionalFields` that I want - I'm not even sure that this would be the right place, as I can't see how to inject the http context at this early stage.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) => builder.AddGelf(options =>
        {
          options.AdditionalFields["machine_name"] = Environment.MachineName;
          options.AdditionalFields["environment_name"] = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;

          options.AdditionalFields["app_version"] = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion;
        }));           
    });
```

My appsettings.json is like so:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "System": "Warning"
    },
    "GELF": {
      "Host": "graylog",
      "Port": 12202, 
      "Protocol": "HTTP", 
      "LogSource": "DataEntry", 
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }  
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
   /* snip */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the recommended approach here it to use a middleware like [this example](https://github.com/mattwcole/gelf-extensions-logging/issues/11#issuecomment-387725521) to add information about the current request as fields:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Register the middleware like so:
        app.UseAppEnvironmentInfo();              
    }
}


public static class RequestAppEnvironmentInfoMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAppEnvironmentInfo(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AppEnvironmentInfoMiddleware>();
    }
}

public class AppEnvironmentInfoMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ILogger<AppEnvironmentInfoMiddleware> _logger;

    public AppEnvironmentInfoMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<AppEnvironmentInfoMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (_logger.BeginScope(("machine_name", Environment.MachineName)))
        using (_logger.BeginScope(("environment_name", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)))
        using (_logger.BeginScope(("app_version", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion)))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```